# Laravel 4 guild site

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a gaming site. There are guilds, and I want to load all the members. The problem is, on the list, it's only showing the leader, not the others. Here's the code:

```
  public function showRequest($name = false)
  {
    if (!$name) return Redirect::to('/');

    $name = urldecode($name);

    $load = Guild::whereName($name)->first();

    if (!$load) return Redirect::to('/');

    $owner_id = $load->ownerid;
    $real = Player::whereId($owner_id)->first();

    $members = Guildsmembers::whereGuildId($load->id)->orderBy('rank_id')->get();
    $count = 0;
    $level = 0;
    $high = 0;
    $low = 0;
    $avg = 0;

    foreach ($members as $tt) {
      $count = $count + Playersonline::wherePlayerId($tt->player_id)->count();
      $player = Player::whereId($tt->player_id)->first();
      $ranks = Guildsranks::whereId($tt->rank_id)->whereGuildId($load->id)->first();
      $cool[$player->name] = array('name' => $player->name, 'level' => $player->level, 'voc' => $player->vocation, 'nickname' => $tt['nick'], 'rank' => $ranks['name']);      

      $level = $level + $cool[$player->name]['level'];

      if ($player->level > $high) 
      {
        $high = $player->level;
        $top_name = $player->name;
      }

      $low = $player->level;
      $low_name = $player->name;

      if ($player->level < $low) 
      {
        $low = $player->level;
        $low_name = $player->name;
      }

      $invited = Guildsinvites::whereGuildId($load->id)->get();
      $invitation = false;

      if ($invited)
      {
        foreach ($invited as $yy)
        {
          $tu = Player::whereId($yy->player_id)->first();
          $join = User::whereId($tu->account_id)->first();

          if (Auth::check())
          {
            if ($join->id == Auth::user()->id)
            {
              $invitation[$yy->player_id] = array('id' => $tu->id, 'name' => $tu->name, 'join' => true);
            } else {
              $invitation[$yy->player_id] = array('id' => $tu->id, 'name' => $tu->name, 'join' => false);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            $invitation[$yy->player_id] = array('id' => $tu->id, 'name' => $tu->name, 'join' => false);
          }
        }
      }
      $stats = array('owner' => $real->account_id, 'low_name' => $low_name, 'low' => $low, 'count' => $count, 'level' => $level, 'top' => $high, 'top_name' => $top_name, 'avg' => $avg);

      return View::make('main.guildview', array('invited' => $invitation, 'msg' => Session::get('errors'), 'stats' => $stats, 'load' => $cool, 'info' => $load));
    }
}
```

On guild list site, it says there are two members, but it only loads one of them. If you have need anything more, just comment it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, you have a guild Id and this

```
$members = Guildsmembers::whereGuildId($load->id)->orderBy('rank_id')->get();
```

indeed ought to load those members whose guild Id is the same as `$load->id`.

And `$load` is a guild:

```
$load = Guild::whereName($name)->first();
```

So I believe your code *ought* to work. I wouldn't call `Guildsmembers::all()` since that would load *all* the guild members of... well, of all the guilds (BTW: `all()` returns a Collection, so you have to use `sortBy` and not `orderBy`).

## TEST 1

Verify that `whereGuildId()` returns both members. If it doesn't, check that indeed the guild Id is correct, and that the scope function for `whereGuildId()` does what it should (better yet, post that part of the code).

If this is OK, then

## TEST 2

Verify that your view *does indeed cycle* between all the members it retrieved and outputs all of them.

## Addendum

I have reindented your code, and unless I'm mistaken, it looks as if you return from your function from inside the loop. So the loop only executes once, and returns only the first element of `$members`.

If this *is* indeed the problem, you'll need first to accumulate whatever information you desire into an object outside of the loop:

```
$memberInfo = array();
foreach ($members as $member) {
...
}
```

then you'll have to pass this object to the view:

```
$memberInfo = array();
foreach ($members as $member) {
...
}
...

return View::make(
    'main.guildview',
    array('invited' => $invitation, 'msg' => Session::get('errors'), 'stats' => $stats, 'load' => $cool, 'info' => $load, 'members' => $memberInfo));
```

What to place into `$memberInfo` unfortunately only you can know. In the View you then iterate `$memberInfo` to display its content.

Comment: @Iserni Could you post a fix? I'm kind of a beginner to all of this, I understand like only the half of what you said haha

Comment: Not really... I have updated my answer, but I know nothing of your models and planned architecture, sorry. Check out the `Views` section of the manual for how to build a loop using a suitable sub-template. That ought to point you in the right direction for what you want to do.

Comment: @Iserni I'll try.. But I doubt I'll fix it haha. Thanks anyway.